Relation between expectation value and counts in reference to qiskit
I am quite confused with the expectation value. When we make measurements using the measurement gates, we get either 0 or 1. When we execute a large number of shots, we get the counts of different states possible. But I really do not understand what is expectation value? Is expectation value somewhat same as counts?
Please explain the relation between expectation value and the counts with some example and code.
Please explain in reference to qiskit.

The expectation value is defined for a quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ and a Hamiltonian $H$ as $\langle\psi|H|\psi\rangle$. Since $H$ is Hermitian, this quantity is a real number, even though both $H$ and $|\psi\rangle$ can have complex coefficients.
Now, how do we evaluate this expression? Well, first of all, we can decompose $H$ into the Pauli basis:
$$H=\sum_{P}\mathrm{Tr}[HP]P$$
where the summation goes over all possible Pauli words over $n$ qubits, assuming $H$ is defined over $n$ qubits. This means that the expectation value can be rewritten as:
$$\langle\psi|H|\psi\rangle=\sum_{P}\mathrm{Tr}[HP]\langle\psi|P|\psi\rangle.$$
So, if, for an arbitrary Pauli word $P$, we know how to compute $\langle\psi|P|\psi\rangle$, then we know how to compute the expectation value.
In order to understand how to compute this quantity, you have to recall what it means to measure with respect to an observable (note that all Pauli words are observable). When you measure a system with respect to an observable, what you will get is an eigenvalue of the observable, and the post-measurement state is the associated eigenstate.
For instance, when we measure in the computational basis, what we really do is measuring in the $Z_1\cdots Z_n$ basis. The eigenvectors are the ones forming the computational basis, and their eigenvalues are $1$ if it contains an even number of $1$, and $-1$ otherwise. For instance, $|00\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$ are associated with the eigenvalue $1$, while $|01\rangle$ and $|10\rangle$ are associated with the eigenvalue $-1$.
Thus, when you measure $|\psi\rangle$ in the computational basis, it's like you sample a random variable that can take the values $-1$ and $1$ with some probability depending on $|\psi\rangle$. You can sample a large number of times this random variable, and its expectation value is exactly equal to $\langle\psi|Z_1\cdots Z_n|\psi\rangle$.
So, we've seen how to compute this expectation value for $P=Z_1\cdots Z_n$. But the problem is that quite often, we are limited in measuring in the computational basis. So, how do we measure in an arbitrary $P$-basis? The neat property is that you can go from $Z_1\cdots Z_n$ to any other Pauli word $P$ by simply applying a change of basis qubit-wise. It means that you can go over every "letter" of you Pauli word and do the following:

If the letter is $I$, store $1$ for this qubit;
If the letter is $Z$, store $-1$ if you measured $|1\rangle$, and $1$ otherwise;
If the letter is $X$, apply an hadamard gate on this qubit. Behave then as in the $Z$ case;
If the letter is $Y$, apply an $S$ gate and an Hadamard gate on this qubit, then behave as in the $Z$ case.

Finally, perform the product of all the results you stored, which will give you either $-1$ or $1$. Sample this random variable enough times, and you'll be able to compute $\langle\psi|P|\psi\rangle$ for any $P$. This is how you link the results from the measures to the expectation value you want to compute.

In Qiskit, computing an expectation value is done via the Estimator primitive. First of all, we have to create the QuantumCircuit that will create our state $|\psi\rangle$. Here, I'll take as an example $\frac{|000\rangle+|011\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

qc = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)

(Note that I've used the Qiskit convention here, where the last wire corresponds to the leftmost qubit). We then want to create our observable by specifying the Pauli words it contains, along with their associated coefficients. For instance, let us consider the observable:
$$O=X_0Z_2+\frac12Y_0Y_1+\frac14Z_1X_2.$$
Note that I'm once again using Qiskit's convention here, so $X_0$ means applying $X$ on the first wire, which corresponds to the last qubit. In order to create an observable using the Pauli basis, you can do it like so:
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp

observable = SparsePauliOp.from_sparse_list(
    [
        ("XZ", [0, 2], 1),
        ("YY", [0, 1], 1/2),
        ("ZX", [1, 2], 1/4),
    ],
    num_qubits=3
)

Now that we have our observable and the circuit to create our state, we can initialize the Estimator object. Note that there are two possible Estimator: the one living in qiskit-aer, and the one living in qiskit-ibm-runtime. Use the first for exact computations, and the second to run on actual Quantum Computers. I'll use the first one here.
from qiskit_aer.primitives import Estimator

estimator = Estimator()
job = estimator.run(qc, observable, shots=10000)
result = job.result()
print(result.values)

You should get a value that is close to $\langle\psi|O|\psi\rangle=\frac12$. You can also compute exactly the expectation value by using numpy:
import numpy as np
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

psi = Statevector(qc).data
O = np.array(observable)
print(psi.T.conj() @ O @ psi)


Thank you @TristanNemoz for help. Please provide some sample qiskit code?

@Manu Sure, here you go

Thank you @TristanNemoz for the response. Thank you for providing me invaluable information like Hamiltonian and observables. I still have one question. For any quantum circuit, if we place measurement gates at end, we get results like {'0000': 27, '0001': 45, ....}. But I am not sure how this counts like results is related to the expectation value?

@Manu Take all the bitstrings containing an even number of 1 and sum their counts together. Let us say that you obtain a number $N$. Let us say that you performed $S$ shots. Then an approximation for the expectation value for the $Z_1\cdots Z_n$ Pauli word is equal to $1-\frac{2N}{S}$. In order to get the expectation value for the other Pauli words, you have to apply the gates I mentioned in my answer before the measurement gates, but after that, the procedure is the same. Once you have the expectation values for all the Pauli words, you can sum them accordingly to your observable .
